# Can't send data from android app to server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I made this code in my app :

```
public class human_Adding_Items extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_human__adding__items);
    final EditText humanButtonadd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    final EditText humanButtonadd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    final Button humanButtonadd3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    final Button humanButtonadd4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    final Button humanButtonadd5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    final Button humanButtonadd6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);

    humanButtonadd3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            humanButtonadd3.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.item_button);
            humanButtonadd4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    humanButtonadd4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            humanButtonadd4.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.item_button);
            humanButtonadd5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    humanButtonadd5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            humanButtonadd5.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.item_button);
            humanButtonadd6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    humanButtonadd6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            humanButtonadd6.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.item_button);

        }
    });
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
    final Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
    final DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
    date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));

    final String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConfirmButtton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String url = "http://192.168.43.27/app_site/api/post.php";
            StringRequest sq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                    Map<String, String>  parr = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parr.put("text1", humanButtonadd1.getText().toString() );
                    parr.put("text2", humanButtonadd2.getText().toString() );
                    return parr;
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

and this my code on server post.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","app_db")
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
$m_text1 = "";
$m_text2 = "";
// recieved from app
$m_text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$m_text2 = $_POST['text2'];
echo "Response: ".$m_text1." ";
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO mytab (text1,text2) VALUES ('$m_text1','$m_text2')";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I try to send text data from app, to server, but it happens nothing...:(
and i don't understand why?!
can u help me pls?
btw last file post.php shows the following error :

> Notice: Undefined index: text1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\app_site\api\post.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: text2 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\app_site\api\post.php on line 14

but it steel insert text1 and text2 in database on refreshing page
P.S im useing local server "xampp", maybe this is the problem?

Comment: is the request making it from the app to the server?

Comment: Your code seem to differ from the [example](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html). You don't add to the queue - nor create it.

Comment: That, the problem i dont know if it comunicate with server or not, but it doest send text data to my db :(

Comment: Is your device in the same network or you are using the emulator? Because emulator uses a virtual network and can't connect by default to the 'real' network that your computer is.

Comment: Yes, im using emulator android and xampp on the same pc.

Answer (score -1):

use volley to communicate with server and database
just add this

in you main gradle file add

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

then in your app gradle file add this in your dependecy

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
```

this is trusted you can follow the tutorial google to get started

> https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: Yes, im using volley